# Where can I find more metal tickets?

Tags: dragon-quest-monsters-joker-2

I'm finally to the point that I can control the charge of my synthesized monsters but synthesizing comes with a lot of required grinding for optimal skill investments. I love being able to quickly grind the various types of metal slimes using the metal tickets, but I don't have enough of them.

Where can I reliably find more metal tickets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place I've found to get metal tickets is the Bemusoleum. You can go there to grind the hunter mechs walking around. They are plentiful and seem to reliably drop them.